# If I extend an abstract class, that is implementing an interface, do I need to rewrite the methods?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, implementation

I have an interface with several methods. I then have an abstract class that defines some of those methods, but also leaves some of the methods abstract. Now I have a class that extends the abstract class. Do I need to write all the methods from the original interface and define them, or does java know that some of them have been implemented by the abstract class?

Comment: What stops you from testing it? Also what do you think, how Java should react on this situation and why?

Comment: why dont you try and let us know?

Comment: the answer is no, you don't need to, but it would not be long for you to check. I advise you delete this question.

Comment: Abstract classes have this very purpose, you can define methods that will be inherited by subclasses. Java also gives you the chance to override methods implemented in the abstract class, so it's up to you.

Comment: Java knows everything. Note that if you are in Java8, a `default` implementation can be provided for method in the interface declaration. And in this case you don't need to implement the method, unless the default imp does not suite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point that you write a concrete (non abstract) class that implements an interface and/or is derived from an abstract base class, that concrete class must provide an implementation for every method it is specified as having. Specified means either by being declared `abstract` in a base class, or being specified by an interface that the class or one of its base classes declares it to implement.

If you write an abstract class that implements an interface and/or is derived from an abstract base class, your new class need not provide an implementation for any of the methods it is specified as having; those remaining methods are either explicitly or implicitly considered as being declared `abstract` by your new class.

Comment: @Finlay Don't bother saying "thanks". Hover your mouse over the up-arrow and down-arrow buttons to the left of the answers you received. Read the tool-tips that the page then shows. Then ask yourself whether you want to click on those buttons.

Comment: sorry, I did try to click accept answer, but it said I had to wait a few minutes. Just returned to do that now.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces methods must be implemented. If the abstract class already implements some of them, you're free to override them in the subclasses or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Interfaces, you declare some methods(), no actual implementation should be there.
And when you implement the interface into a abstract class, the declaration of those methods is present in that abstract class. It is up to you to decide whether to define the methods here or not.
when you extend these methods in concrete class(one which will be used to create objects), every methods needed to be defined and since if you already defined some methods in abstract class you don't need to do it again,but you can do it.